# NSDateFormatter gets stringFromDate wrong

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have a string as follows:

> 2012-11-01

And I want to get a string representing the day from that. So this is how I approach it:

```
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[dateFormatter setDateFormat: @"yyyy-mm-dd"];

NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString: @"2012-11-01"];

[dateFormatter setDateFormat: @"EEE"];

NSString *string = [dateFormatter stringFromDate: date];

NSLog(@"%@", string);
```

And the output is:

> Sun

When it really should be:

> Thu

(If my calculations are correct!)

So what is the problem here? Is this an internal bug? Something wrong with my code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your first date format string to:

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat: @"yyyy-MM-dd"]; // Capital MM for month
```

It should work then.

Comment: Yeah that worked, strange that would happen... why is it MM has to be in capital?

Comment: Because lowercase m is minutes.